# Convert function with callback to async promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Any ideas on how to implement this more elegantly using async that returns a promise instead of callbacks?

```
const webShare = (data) => {
    if (navigator.share) { 
        navigator.share({
           title: data.title,
           text: data.text,
           url: data.url
        }).then(() => {
            if (typeof data.successCallback === 'function') {
                data.successCallback();
            }
        }).catch(console.error);
    } else {
        if (typeof data.noSupportCallback === 'function') {
            data.noSupportCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
webShare({
    url: window.location.href,
    noSupportCallback: this.handleCopyDesktop
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return a promise that gets rejected with a `NoSupportError`:

```
class NoSupportError extends Error {}

const webShare = (data) => {
    if (navigator.share) { 
        return navigator.share({
           title: data.title,
           text: data.text,
           url: data.url
        })
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new NoSupportError());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
webShare({
    url: window.location.href,
}).catch(err => {
    if (err instanceof NoSupportError) {
        this.handleCopyDesktop();
    } else {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also use error codes on a normal error object, just match the error message, anything. Alternatively fulfill the promise with a value that is somehow distinguishable from the normal result of `navigator.share`